# Maven child module profile

Tags: java, maven

I have a maven multi-module project.
The parent has a test profile and includes child a  in the profile itself.

1. If I run mvn -P test from child module, will parent's "test" profile get executed?
2. What if I want to provide a test profile for a specific child module only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No. A child inherits the configuration from the parent, but it's not a buildchain relationship. While, since you have specified the child as a module, the child will be built when the parent gets built, from the point of view of the child in this case, the parent is another dependency of type "pom".
2. You just execute the build for the child with your test profile.

Note that:

- you would able to see it for yourself just by building your project,
- [inheritance (children) and aggregation (modules) are separate concepts in Maven](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#POM_Relationships).